# CloudWatch: Count number of occurrences of a specific string in logfiles

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have logfiles which contain specific spring patterns. These string patterns occur frequently per log event.
For example:

```
<abc>108</abc>xyz<abc>22222</abc>
```

I want to count the occurence of `<abc>` for a specific period of time in CloudWatch.

I did this to count the occurences per minute:

```
fields @timestamp
| parse @message "<abc>" as abc
| filter strcontains(@message, "<abc>")
| stats count(abc) by bin(1m)
```

But it just counts one for a log event that contains `<abc>` at least once. In the example above I would expect two.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a single function that will give you what you need, but you can do something like this:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter strcontains(@message, "<abc>")
| fields (strlen(@message)-strlen(replace(@message, "<abc>", ""))) / strlen("<abc>")
```

Comment: This is a bit cleaner:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /<abc>/
| stats count(@message) as Occurrences
```

you may need to escape the <> on abc

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works but this seems a bit cleaner as it gives a clear count:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /<abc>/
| stats count(@message) as Occurrences
```

may have to escape <> around abc,

also for anyone coming across this you have to enter this into cloudwatch log insights, i came across this post for my own similar use case and wasn't clear where to enter the query.

Comment: This does not count the total number of occurrences when there can be multiple occurrences in a single line. This counts the number of lines that have `<abc>`.

Comment: ah fair point, i suppose based on your use case this may not work. For me / others with same use case, this is a cleaner solution since i only have one occurrence per line ever (basically matching a 'completed xyz' phrase), and having the count as a single number is nicer.  But thanks for pointing out the limitation.