# AWS Log insights, parse all occurrences in a log

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a question concerning log insights in aws. How is it possible to fetch all the occurrences in a log ? I tried with and without a regex and the parse will only fetch the first occurrence.

I have a log like this (and multiple entries of this kind of log):

> [ERROR] - [{'id': 'id1'}, {'id': 'id2'}, {'id': 'id3'}]

And I want to extract all the ids, so I tried :

```
parse @message "id': '*'" as id
```

which return only **id1** (the first occurrence) by log

and I also tried a regex :

```
parse @message /id': '(?<id>\S*)'/
```

which return only **id1** (the first occurrence) as well by log

I expect something like [id1, id2, id3] or multiple line in the result (one by match).

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a nice way to handle this, it seems like we can't get more than one result from one log

But maybe you can use the practice shared on the answer linked below and find how many items exist in each message
and you can also get list of the values by string manipulation

```
fields (strlen(@message)-strlen(replace(@message, "'id'", ""))) / strlen("'id'") as count, 
       replace(replace(replace(@message, "}", ""), "},", ","), "{'id': ", "") as list
# would return 3, ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73254710/1762994

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for similar solution, but i couldn't get any of the presented ones to work. I have made it manually, by having predefined what's the maximum number of values i'd expect to see, like so:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter @message like /"value":/
| parse @message '"value": "*"*' as msg, rest
| parse rest '"value": "*"*' as msg2, rest2
| parse rest2 '"value": "*"*' as msg3, rest3
| parse rest3 '"value": "*"*' as msg4, rest4
| parse rest4 '"value": "*"*' as msg5, rest5
| parse rest5 '"value": "*"*' as msg6, rest6
| display msg, msg2, msg3, msg4, msg5, msg6
```

You can of course go as long as you wish (i think, idk cuz i stopped at 20)

My use case was to find all values of matching JSON tag that is in the message.

I know it's not ideal, but worked well enough for me.