# Cloudwatch insights parse fields from array of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have this sample log and I want retrieve all values of a certain field and concatenate them on the log insight result. I tried to parse this but it can only retrieve its first occurrence.

Sample Log:

```
Field   Value
@message                      {"level":"INFO","message":"Event","timestamp":"2023-04-05T20:27:42.606Z","event":{"version":"0","time":"2023-04-05T20:27:41Z","resources":[""],"detail":{"Entries":[{"Code":"C25"},{"Code":"C27"}]}}}
@timestamp                    1680726462608
event.detail.Entries.0.Code   C25
event.detail.Entries.1.Code   C27
event.time                    2023-04-05T20:27:41Z
event.version                 0
level                         INFO
message                       Event
timestamp                     2023-04-05T20:27:42.606Z
```

What I want to achieve:

```
@timestamp                    code
2023-04-05T20:27:42.606Z      C25,C27
```

What I tried:

```
filter message like /Event/
| parse @message '{"Code":"*"}' as code
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

What I got:

```
@timestamp                    code
2023-04-05T20:27:42.606Z      C25
```

The query cannot retrieve the code "C27". How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you still need the answer, but i've had similar issue, with the difference that my objects were much bigger and more nested. I've tried a few solutions available around but nothing worked for me due to sheer complexity of the data i work with. I've managed to invent a (little hacky and manual) workaround, see below for my answer if you wanna check it out.

[AWS Log insights, parse all occurrences in a log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73308111)